# DomMarker blocks Polyline events underneath

Tags: here-api

I'm using HereMaps JS sdk 3.1.15.1

1. I've created a Polyline
2. i have created a DomMarker on pointermove event across the Polyline
3. i update DomMarker's geometry with the event's coordinates
4. DomMarker appears on the Polyline but when I continue to move the
   cursor, events on the Polyline below no longer fire

Is there a workaround? With goodle sdk you have "clickable" and "draggable" properties on the analog of DomMarker so events go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using below code snippet.

```
// enable the event system
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map)),

//create the line
line=new H.map.Polyline(new H.geo.Strip([ 52.5032, 13.2790,0,
                                          52.5102, 13.2818,0,
                                          52.5121, 13.3224,0,
                                          52.5145, 13.3487,0,
                                          52.5139, 13.3501,0,
                                          52.5146, 13.3515,0,
                                          52.5161, 13.3769,0])
                       );
//draw the line
map.addObject(line);

//add tap-listener
map.addEventListener('tap', function(e){

  var pointer = e.currentPointer,
      //create geo.Point
      latLng  = map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX, pointer.viewportY),
      //get current strip
      strip=line.getStrip();

  //push point to strip
  strip.pushPoint(latLng);

  //set updated strip
  line.setStrip(strip);
});
```